# Can Not Login, Bios Password

Tags: bios, 1password

I have a lenovo ThinkPad laptop, with 2 user accounts; Administrator and guest account.
I can not login to the guest account, as I forgot the password, and when I turn on the PC, the login screen comes with the default user being the guest account, and without the option of "switch user" so that I log in to the Admin Account.
Already tried restarting the PC, removing battery, but all hopeless.
Trying to access the boot menu to boot from CD, it asks for a bios password which I don't know too.. 
Any help on how to login to the admin account, or reset the bios password?

Comment: When you say you removed the Battery, do you mean the external large Lithium Ion Battery or the small disc shaped internal battery? Only the latter would reset the BIOS.

Comment: What Windows is it running?

Comment: its windows 8..

Comment: I would not remove the CMOS battery, cases are known where the thinkpad detects this as trying to bypass the BIOS pw, blocking the BIOS completely and rendering the laptop useless.